# максимальная сумма двух элементов в массиве

Tags: алгоритм

Каким способом эту задачу можно решить быстрее всего?

Пробовал написать по разному, пока это самый быстрый вариант.

```
long sum =0;
    int left =0;
    int right = arr.length-1;
    int max = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while(left<right){
        sum++;
        if(i == right){   
            if(arr[left]+arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[left]+arr[i];
            }
            left++;
            right--;
            i = left;
        }
        if(arr[left]+arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[left]+arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[right] + arr[i] > max){      
            max = arr[right]+arr[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println(sum);
```

При размере массива в 100к, решает примерно 5с. sum в итоге = 2500кк.
Я уверен что есть решение быстрее, но к сожалению не могу его найти. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Может сортировать массив по убыванию и взять сумму двух первых элементов.

Comment: А почему бы не пройтись по массиву, запоминая два наибольших элемента?

Comment: @tilin по моему это самый быстрый вариант, кончено если массив уже не отсортирован. Сидел придумывал велосипед, эх ... Спасибо.

Comment: @Micahil все же самый быстрый будет, наверное, у VladD

Comment: @tilin, не наверное, а точно - решение VladD работает за линейное время, тогда как как вариант с сортировкой - за линейно-логарифмическое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сложите два наибольших элемента в массиве:

```py
max1, max2 = max(L[0], L[1]), min(L[0], L[1])
for x in L:
    if x > max2:
        max1, max2 = (x, max1) if x > max1 else (max1, x)

print(max1 + max2)
```

[Пример](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=L%20%3D%20%5B7,%20-5,%205,%20-2,%20-5,%2010,%204,%207,%20-1,%208%5D%0Amax1,%20max2%20%3D%20max%28L%5B0%5D,%20L%5B1%5D%29,%20min%28L%5B0%5D,%20L%5B1%5D%29%0Afor%20x%20in%20L%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3E%20max2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20max1,%20max2%20%3D%20%28x,%20max1%29%20if%20x%20%3E%20max1%20else%20%28max1,%20x%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28max1%20%2B%20max2%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=27&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда, стало интересно, насколько отличаются алгоритмы по времени работы.

Написал программку (на С++) с тремя алгоритмами - линейный, авторский :) и полный перебор.

Результат:

```
Линейный алгоритм:       1999985078 for 46 mks
Алгоритм автора вопроса: 1999997406 for 4324499 mks
Полный перебор:          1999985078 for 5021863 mks
```

Понятно, что время абсолютно точно не меряется, но в 100000 раз - это как раз и отличает для 100000 элементов O(N) от O(N<sup>2</sup>) :)

Итого, алгоритм автора не только работает практически как полный перебор, но еще и подвирает... :( Где именно - искать не стал.

```
#define  NOMINMAX
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <mutimer.hpp>

using namespace std;

constexpr int length = 100000;
constexpr int maxValue = 1000000000;
vector<int> arr;



int Micahil(const vector<int>& arr)
{
    int left =0;
    int right = arr.size() - 1;
    int max = 0;
    int i = 1;

    while(left<right){
        if(i == right){
            if(arr[left]+arr[i] > max){
                max = arr[left]+arr[i];
            }
            left++;
            right--;
            i = left;
        }
        if(arr[left]+arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[left]+arr[i];
        }
        if(arr[right] + arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[right]+arr[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return max;
}

int Harry(const vector<int>& arr)
{
    int max0 = arr[0], max1 = arr[1];
    if (max0 < max1) swap(max0, max1);
    for(size_t i = 2; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max1)
        {
            max1 = arr[i];
            if (max0 < max1) swap(max0, max1);
        }
    }
    return max0 + max1;
}

int Exhaust(const vector<int>& arr)
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < length; ++j)
        {
            int sum = arr[i] + arr[j];
            if (sum > max) max = sum;
        }
    }
    return max;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, maxValue);
    arr.reserve(length);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        arr.push_back(dis(gen));

    {
        muTimer mu;
        int res = Harry(arr);
        mu.stop();
        cout << res << " for " << mu.duration() << "mks\n";
    }
    {
        muTimer mu;
        int res = Micahil(arr);
        mu.stop();
        cout << res << " for " << mu.duration() << "mks\n";
    }
    {
        muTimer mu;
        int res = Exhaust(arr);
        mu.stop();
        cout << res << " for " << mu.duration() << "mks\n";
    }

}
```

(`muTimer` - мой измеритель времени :))

Comment: да, иногда врет. Тоже искать не стал так как все оказалось намного проще.